# unity android sdk bulid error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I was working on a game for android on unity, and after I downloaded the android sdk, the ndk, the google, usb drivers and the jdk, I tried to build, but everytime I did so it popped an error to me which was
`Exeption in "main" thread java.lang.NoClassFoundError`

and it has been driving me nuts. I got a similar error in unity which was android is not a valid command, then I tried to update the sdk in the cmd with the command 
`android update sdk`
which was correct but I got the same error, and so on with 
`sdkmanager --update sdk`
Any help would be appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Wrong answer first time. Try downgrading to JDK 8.

Comment: I did so, yet it didn't make a change